# Python package not importing after update on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, mpi

I recently updated all the pip packages I have installed and I can no longer import mpi4py. If I try to load it I get an error `ImportError: No module named mpi4py`, both in interactive mode and when running a script. (It also happens for both python 2.7 and python 3.) (If it's relevant I'm still using OS X Yosemite.)

running `$ python -c "import mpi4py; print(mpi4py.__file__)"` the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
ImportError: No module named mpi4py`
```

and the output from `pip show -f mpi4py` is:

```
Name: mpi4py
Version: 3.0.0
Summary: Python bindings for MPI
Home-page: https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/
Author: Lisandro Dalcin
Author-email: dalcinl@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Files:
  mpi4py-3.0.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst,mpi4py-3.0.0.dist-info/INSTALLER,mpi4py-3.0.0.dist-info/METADATA,mpi4py-3.0.0.dist-info/RECORD,mpi4py-3.0.0.dist-info/WHEEL,mpi4py-3.0.0.dist-info/metadata.json,mpi4py-3.0.0.dist-info/top_level.txt,mpi4py/MPI.pxd,mpi4py/MPI.so,mpi4py/__init__.pxd,mpi4py/__init__.py,mpi4py/__init__.pyc,mpi4py/__main__.py,mpi4py/__main__.pyc,mpi4py/bench.py,mpi4py/bench.pyc,mpi4py/dl.so,mpi4py/futures/__init__.py,mpi4py/futures/__init__.pyc,mpi4py/futures/__main__.py,mpi4py/futures/__main__.pyc,mpi4py/futures/_base.py,mpi4py/futures/_base.pyc,mpi4py/futures/_lib.py,mpi4py/futures/_lib.pyc,mpi4py/futures/aplus.py,mpi4py/futures/aplus.pyc,mpi4py/futures/pool.py,mpi4py/futures/pool.pyc,mpi4py/futures/server.py,mpi4py/futures/server.pyc,mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi.pxi,mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.MPI.h,mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.MPI_api.h,mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.h,mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.i,mpi4py/libmpi.pxd,mpi4py/mpi.cfg,mpi4py/run.py,mpi4py/run.pyc
```

If I run `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` I get:

```
['', '$HOME',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/Users/cns08/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

and `echo $PATH` gives me:

```
/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin
:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

Comment: This is usually an xcode error and does not relate to your issue (I also get this error while all python packages work fine on my machine). Can you post the output you get by running `$ python -c "import mpi4py; print(mpi4py.__file__)"` and `$ pip show -f mpi4py`?

Comment: ah, okay, thanks. I've added those to the post

Comment: That's strange - the file `mpi4py/__init__.py` is there, so the module should be importable. What is your python version? `$ python -V`

Comment: My python version is `Python 2.7.10`

Comment: Oh, I see it now - you probably have two pythons, the system one and brewed one. Can you please execute `$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` to confirm it or prove me wrong? Also `$ echo $PATH` would be neat.

Comment: What I suspect is that something happened with your `PATH` variable so the brewed python is not preferred over system python anymore.

Comment: I've added both of those to the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159677/discussion-between-hoefling-and-rgwinston).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Together, we have found the issue - you have two installation of python on your machine - the system one (`/usr/bin/python`) and the "brewed" one, installed via `$ brew install python` and located under `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python`. It was missing in `PATH`, so the commands `$ python ...` referred to the system python. All the `$ pip ...` commands, though, referred to the brewed python. In particular, `mpi4py` was installed and updated for the brewed version, while the system python could not access it. The solution was to add the brewed python back to `PATH`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

in the `~/.bash_profile`.

---

As for me, I prefer not to use brewed python to avoid this kind of errors. Although this is highly opinionated as many prefer not to tinkle with the system python to not to break it. Also, you will require `sudo` for this configuration! Still, I didn't encounter any issues so far with my approach, so this is what I did:

1. List all the packages you have installed for the brewed python:

   ```
   $ pip list --format=freeze > packages-with-brewed-python.txt
   ```

   We will need this file to restore them with the system python.
2. If you have brewed python installed, deactivate it by removing or commenting the export line from `~/.bash_profile`
3. Install `pip` for the system python (this is the only step you will need `sudo` for):

   ```
   $ sudo easy_install pip
   ```

   You now have a system installation of `pip`what you can use to add packages. Check it by issuing `pip -V`:

   ```
    $ pip -V
    pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
   ```
4. Uninstall brewed python:

   ```
   $ brew uninstall python
   ```
5. Every package I install with `pip`, I do with `--user` key so I don't need `sudo` anymore. So to restore the packages with the new `pip`, run

   ```
   $ pip install --user -r packages-with-brewed-python.txt
   ```
6. If you wish, you can now cleanup the brewed python's packages to free some space:

   ```
   $ rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
   ```

The only limitation with this approach for me is that I need to install the packages with `--user` key so they are only available on my user account (nothing is installed system-wide). I also work under a user account that does not have administrator privileges (I have a separate account for that), so basically, `sudo` is a no-go for me anyway.

Again, this is no recommendation whatsoever, but it saved many headaches for me compared to the necessity of distincting between two identical python versions installed.